# JSON request in node.js on Windows fails to pull data

Tags: web-services, node.js, flickr

I've written a node.js page to grab some data from the flick API and then insert it into a database.

The code works perfectly on linux-- but when I moved it to a Windows machine running the latest version of node.js it seems that the data isn't parsing correctly.

```
var options = {
  host: 'api.flickr.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=aa96a1b927fbf005374eb19d811ed529&tags=cars&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&page='+page
};          

http.get(options, function(res){        
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk){        
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end',function(){ 
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.dir(obj.photos.photo); // empty array on Windows, fine on linux!
    })
});
```

I also verified the data by making a test request in a web browser for the same data-- the `photos.photo` element should definitely be populated.

Is there a reason this could be happening, such as I'm missing a library or plugin on Windows? Or could memory be affecting this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to share your api key on stackoverflow?

Comment: Is the `*/` in the line above the `JSON.parse` just a typo?

Comment: @jsalonen- that's the public key used in their demo stuff, not the real key!

Comment: @JohnnyHK-- yes, that's a typo. Sorry!

Comment: What `page` value are you requesting in the URL?  I tried this with `page=0` on Windows and it worked fine.

Comment: @JohnnyHK-- page is randomly chosen from 1-5. I'll try statically setting that value.

Comment: @JohnnyHK-- damn, you are right! The page was being selected out of range from the results, which meant it did return an empty array of images, though I would have expected an error message. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by JohnnyHK in the comments, the random page being appended to the API url was requesting pages that were out of range for the API. Rather than return an error (like a 404 or something for no page existing) the API returns an empty photos array.